# hanlde exception in laravel livewire function param

Tags: php, laravel, exception, parameters, laravel-livewire

any way to handle exceptions for model type parameters?

```php
public function removeItem(Item $item){
    //code...
}
```

I get a 404 error screen when the function receives an id that does not exist, I would prefer to launch a simple alert that does not destroy the form.

Comment: Can you use the `report` helper? You can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/errors). If not, what about the regular `try / catch`?

Comment: thanks, try/catch is what I'm using, but for the `removeItem(Item $item)` form where I pass the id and it brings me the model or 404 error how do I handle exceptions if it doesn't even go into the function?

Answer (score 1):

> [Action parameters](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/actions#action-parameters) are also capable of directly resolving a model by its key using a type hint.

That means by type hinting your `$item` as `Item` livewire tries to find an `Item` by the given id. But if that id does not exist a matching exception will be thrown. You therefore do not enter the `removeItem` method.

To handle the exception from within the function you can just get rid of the type hint and fetch the model by yourself:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

public function removeItem(int $item)
{
    try {
        Item::findOrFail($item);

        // your code...
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $modelNotFoundException) {
       // launch your simple alert
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        // remaining error handling
    }
}
```